# Dart scripts that invoke scripts by importing them

Tags: dart

I have this setup:

```
├── bin
│   ├── all.dart
│   ├── details
│   │   ├── script1.dart
│   │   └── script2.dart
|   |    .....
```

*all.dart* simply imports *script1.dart* and *script2.dart* and calls their *main*. The goal is to have a bunch of scripts under *details* that can be run individually. Additionally I want a separate *all.dart* script that can run them all at once. This will make debugging individual scripts simpler, yet still allowing all to run.

*all.dart*

```dart
import 'details/script1.dart' as script1;
import 'details/script2.dart' as script2;

main() {
  script1.main();
  script2.main();
}
```

*script1.dart*

```dart
main() => print('script1 run');
```

*script2.dart*

```dart
main() => print('script2 run');
```

So, this is working and I see the print statements expected when running *all.dart* but I have two issues.

First, I have to softlink *packages* under *details*. Apparently pub does not propagate packages softlinks down to subfolders. Is this expected or is there a workaround?

Second, there are errors flagged in *all.dart* at the point of the second import statement. The analyzer error is:

```dart
The imported libraries 'script1.dart' and 'script2.dart' should not have the same name ''
```

So my guess is since I'm importing other scripts as if they are libraries and since they do not have the *library script[12];* statement at the top they both have the same name - the empty name?

*Note:* Originally I had all of these under *lib* and I could run them as scripts specifying a suitable *--package-root* on the command line even though they were libraries with *main*. But then to debug I need to run in Dart Editor, which is why I'm moving them to *bin*. Perhaps the editor should allow libraries under *lib* with a *main* to be run as a script since they run outside the editor just fine? The actual differences between script/library seems a bit unnecessary (as other scripting languages allow files to be both).

How do I clean this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the actual question is.

- If a library has not library statement then the empty string is used as a name.
  Just add a library statement with an unique name to fix this.
- Adding symlinks to subdirectories solves the problem with the imports for scripts in subdirectories.
  I do this regularily.
  It was mentioned several times in dartbug.com that symlinks should go away entirely but I have no idea how long this will take.
- I have never tried to put script files with a main in `lib` but it is just against the package layout conventions and I guess this is why DartEditor doesn't support it.

Comment: How to clean up warnings and no softlink?

On third point it gets to question of real difference between script and lib. Why have qualms about library with a main, but not have qualms about a script with main (and by package layout convention not a lib) requiring a library statement at top to get rid of warnings?

Not sure how the editor determines if it can run; but one solution would be the editor checks for *main* and if present runs *'dart --package-root'* set to packages' package folder. Then no softlinks needed *and* anything with is a main (even a library) can also be run as a script.

Comment: I don't know about `lib` but otherwise you should be able to create a launch configuration for your script and add custom arguments like `--package-root`. A bit cumbersome because you need a configuration for each file. The unique library name is needed for canonicalization AFAIK.

Comment: No, too much. I'll stick with internal naming of scripts (libs) and doing softlink for now as it works without analysis warnings.

Comment: I have one project with similar requirements and also do it this way.